# How to make Python constantly accept input from events

Tags: python, loops, events, while-loop

I'm coding a simple game, and I've got the graphics down and most of the interaction coded.  My only problem is if I try to code input i have to code it for every single iteration.  This is far too laborious to do for a full-length game, so is there a way to make it so the game will accept input constantly with only a few lines of code? I've heard of while loops but only understand how to do it with integers, and some of the other code on this site didn't make sense.

Comment: Have you heard of pygame?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you mean keyboard input or text input.
If you want to have multiple text input you can have a loop accepting input with raw_input like so:

```
while True:
  input = raw_input('Some input: ')
  if input == "exit":
    break
  print "You said: " , input
```

If you simply want keyboard input, you can do this on windows:

```
import msvcrt
while True:
  if msvcrt.kbhit():
    print "Key pressed: %s" % msvcrt.getch()
```

Here is an example using [pygame](http://www.pygame.org/hifi.html):

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_mode((640,480)) # open 640x480 window

running = True
while running: # repeat forever
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # get event from the event queue
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False         
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_a:
                print "You pressed the key: 'a'"
            if event.key == pygame.K_b:
                print "Do something else"
pygame.quit();
```